# Having difficulties running AC compressors from a generator on a boat

Tags: frequency, generator, rpm

I have a problem that has me stuck and it’s marine related.

When my ship is on shore power the AC system works perfect with no defects the evaporator and compressors comes on.

When I switch over to generator power, this is the scenario:

When the generator is online the RPM is constant at 1500 RPM and freq is 50 Hz (Where I am uses 50 Hz). I can use all other equipment on the ship but when I turn on the AC the compressors don't start and the rpms and frequency drops and produces a busbar freq low alarm.  Freq drops to ~46 Hz and the rpmss go to roughly 1420.

I have two generators on the ship and the problem exist with either genset. If I switch back over to shore power the AC works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Fix the runon sentence and formatting.  Remember that you are asking a bunch of volunteers for a favor.  Show some respect.

Comment: Usually, generator RPM and electrical frequency are locked together. It is no surprise that when frequency drops, RPM drops. Why do they drop? They drop because suddenly a large electrical load has been connected to the generator demanding many Amps. This creates a large mechanical load on the prime mover which causes it to slow down. Even though you think the AC unit is "not even trying to start." I can almost guarantee you that something is drawing a lot of current. Otherwise the prime mover would not have trouble trying to maintain 1500 RPM.

Comment: Run the two gensets in parallel first, so they can share the load. Then try to start AC

Comment: VFD on the AC compressor comes to mind.

Answer (score 7):

You have provided no current measurements so we have no idea how much of an overload you are presenting to your generator.

Your options are:

- Get a bigger generator.
- Shed load during AC compressor starting so that the AC doesn't overload the generator.
- Sequence the AC compressors, if there is more than one, so that only one is drawing starting current at any time.
- See if a soft-start is available for the compressors.
- See if the compressors can be started off-line. i.e., Is there any decompression valve that will reduce the mechanical load on the motor during start.

Comment: We only start one compressor at a time but the problem is the compressor is not even trying to start so its not really overloading the genset.

Comment: "... so its not really overloading the genset." versus "... when i go to turn on the AC the compressors don't start and the rpm's and freq drops and get a busbar freq low alarm." These statements contradict each other.

Comment: I placed my meter on each of the 3 phases when i turn the switch, there isn't any current draw because the contactor which is suppose to be energized isn't being so the compressors don't start but what has me stuck is why it works on shore power when in reality when i switch to genset the shore supply disconnects from the bus bar and the generator connects to the bus bar. Can high resistance in the cables cause a different reaction to when on Shore power and genset or i can rule that out?

Comment: Well then you've got to figure out what is overloading the genset when you turn on the AC. Sorry, but I don't think I can fix your ship from my bed. This site isn't meant for repair questions but if you have a particular engineering design question you can modify your question.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong compressor, maybe there is an error in the numbering. You said "We only start one compressor at a time" therefore one could conclude you have more then one. You also said "when i go to turn on the AC the compressors don't start and the rpm's and freq drops and get a busbar freq low alarm." therefore something is pulling a lot of load. Furthermore "I placed my meter on each of the 3 phases when i turn the switch, there isn't any current draw because the contactor which is suppose to be energized I", so check a different compressor.

Comment: What worked in the past with the gensets??  We have no history nor specs on surge load and capacity.

Comment: Can you put the current meter on the generator output when you try to start the AC? Pretty sure you will see a large current increase.

Comment: Will put the meter on the generator tomorrow and see if there is a increase in the current when trying to turn on the compressor and get back to you on the findings.

Answer (score 3):

AC compressors are the canonical nasty startup load, they tend to have VERY high starting current demands.

I would bet that for a few cycles at startup the things are drawing a huge amount more current then you would think and that your generating sets just do not have the combination of rotating mass, throttle response and available prime mover torque to ride this out. Note that the startup transient current demand will not be of long duration, and your metering may or may not see it, depends on what you are using.

Fitting some combination of soft starters and unload valves to the compressors is the real answer, together with sequencing the startup so only one compressor starts at a time. In the interim, try bringing both generators on line as a synced pair before starting a compressor, it might give you enough to hold the network frequency up.

One other dirty hack I have seen is a large sync induction motor with a heavy flywheel left on the bus, it acts as a load that resists frequency changes by becoming a generator when the frequency drops, somewhat nasty from a control loop perspective, but it got us out of trouble.